# Why do I need to specify references and pointers instead of plain variables in C

Tags: c, pointers, reference, ansi-c

What exactly is stopping the compiler from understanding the following program if all references and pointers were reduced to just plain variables?

```
/* Takes three numbers as input and returns their sum and average as output */

#include <stdio.h>

void sum_n_avg(double arg1, double arg2, double arg3, double 
*sum, double *avg);

int main(){
  double one, two, three, sum, avg;
  printf("Enter three numbers> ");
  scanf("%lf%lf%lf", &one, &two, &three);
  sum_n_avg(one, two, three, &sum, &avg);
  printf("%lf is the sum, %lf is the average\n", sum, avg);
}

void sum_n_avg(double arg1, double arg2, double arg3, double *sum, double *avg){
  *sum = arg1 + arg2 + arg3;
  *avg = (*sum) / 3;
}
```

This question isn't "how do I do the thing" but rather "why does C do *this* thing?"

Any intuition here would be really helpful - links to other discussions like "why use pointers" or "when to use pointers" are not what i'm looking for.

Comment: This is the why -> "/* Takes three numbers as input and returns their sum and average as output */
" The pointers are used to return 2 values from the function, instead of just one. (BTW, C doesn't have references).

Comment: This seems like the answer is "C must adhere to a constraint because of another different constraint". If C needs to see ampersands and asterisks to be able to return more than one value from a function, the obvious question from there is... why? Specifically what is stopping the compiler from understanding the program if all pointers and references were removed?

Comment: If you are seeking an open-ended discussion on the reasoning behind the design of the C language, then that is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Look with all respect I was pretty explicit - "specifically what is stopping the compiler from understanding the program if all pointers and references were removed?"

Comment: It's not that the compiler wouldn't understand it, it is that it would not then be the same program or do the same thing.

Comment: C passes all function arguments by "value" (as opposed to by "reference, or by "name", etc.)  This means that the called function gets its own, local copies of the arguments.  It can change them, but those changes are strictly local to the called function.  If you want the changes to be visible to the caller, then you need to pass pointers to the destination variables so that the called function can modify them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sum_n_avg()` takes 5 inputs: 3 are `double`, 2 are pointers.

```
void sum_n_avg(double arg1, double arg2, double arg3, double *sum, double *avg);
```

There is to no information coming out of the function other than 2 pointers that indicate where to store data.

---

> What exactly is stopping the compiler from understanding the following program if all references and pointers were reduced to just plain variables?

If one removes "references" from `sum_n_avg()` then

```
sum_n_avg_noref(double arg1, double arg2, double arg3, double  sum, double avg)
```

is a function that takes 5 `double` inputs.

There is to no information coming out of the function nor indication that a parameter should be anything other than an "input" only.

---

> why does C do this thing

C succeeded because of a simple design. Function arguments are inputs.  The return value is the output.

References complicated things.

To accommodate more than one output, code passes in pointers as locations to store data.

Comment: This made so much sense, thank you. I sincerely hope I have understood correctly. 
Rather than the function allocating memory locations and saying "these locations hold these values", it needs to address already-existing allocated memory and then say "these memory locations that already existed before I did anything, now hold these values". Is that correct?

Comment: @DavideLorino Close.  With `sum_n_avg(one, two, three, &sum, &avg);` and `sum_n_avg(double arg1, double arg2, double arg3, double *sum_, double *avg)`, `sum_` points to a valid location.  It is possible that `sum_n_avg()` will use that pointer to know where to store the _sum_.  Another function might have only read from that location, or just printed the pointer, or read and wrote the location or ...